# When will the extension for speechrecognition (webspeech api) for firefox browser be released?

Tags: javascript, firefox, speech-recognition

I want to know the tentative dates and also if a workaround is available right now for it to work on firefox

Comment: The extension? For me the Web Speech API works perfectly fine in Firefox 59

Comment: I meant this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529098/enable-web-speech-api-on-mozilla-firefox   Previously, permissions were required. how I could allow it on my client's browser when they go to my app? How do we ask for different permissions and allow, for example, media.webspeech.synth.enabled

Comment: According to this [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1248897) raised at mozilla, this was opened 2 years ago, but still no signs of closure yet! :( I am also really looking forward to getting this feature in Firefox.

@Luca, would appreciate you telling us how you got Web Speech API to run fine on Firefox 59?